# How to set product name (post title) from product image EXIF meta title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to add my products with as little human input as possible.
Therefor I'm looking for a solution to grab the title tag which is in my added product image and put it in the Product name field on or before saving the product. Any attempts to achieve this are failing because WordPress "thinks" that no title is given (so no slug could be generated). At least I think that this is the case.

See screenshot of the field

[image: This is the field I'm talking about]

I tried to use a code snippet I found here on SO and to rework it to a working solution but I fail to get it right.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
function fcsp_set_title_on_save( $post_id ) {

$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$filemeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_thumbnail_id, FALSE );

// Set this variable to false initially.
static $updated = false;

// If title has already been set once, bail.
if ( $updated ) {
    return;
}

// Since we're updating this post's title, set this
// variable to true to ensure it doesn't happen again.
$updated = true;
$title          = $filemeta['image_meta']['title'];

// Update the post's title.
wp_update_post( [
    'ID'         => $post_id,
    'post_title' => $title,
] );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'fcsp_set_title_on_save' );
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in function.php if this is woocommerce you are using (I think rather than custom post type )

```
if(class_exists('WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes')) {
class wcsave extends WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes {
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_boxes' ), 1, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::save', 10, 2 );
}
public function save_meta_boxes( $post_id, $post ) {
    //$_POST enter your post data here, this will help to control the post request from product woocommerce
    //if product is updating don't execute image title code section
    if(!empty($post->post_title)) {
        return;
    }
    //if new product is being added.
    if(!empty($_POST['post_ID']) && $post_id == $_POST['post_ID']) {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        $attachment_data = get_post( $post_thumbnail_id,OBJECT ); 
        $title = count($attachment_data) > 0 ? $attachment_data->post_title : "PRODUCT-".$post_id;
        remove_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_boxes' ) , 1, 2 );
        wp_update_post( [
            'ID'         => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_status' => $post->post_status
        ] );
        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_meta_boxes' ) , 1, 2 );
    }
}
}
new wcsave();
}
```

But please note, as I've tested you need at least some other info along with product image you are uploading like product description, rest it will save the image name as product title.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is passed from `$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );`. I have updated my function to incorporate the declaration of the variable but no avail. No Product title is set. Any ideas?

Comment: can you use it like this, inside function above `wp_update_post( [
    'ID'         => $post_id,
    'post_title' => $title,
] );` add `remove_action( 'save_post', 'fcsp_set_title_on_save' );` and then after `wp_update_pos` again add `add_action('save_post','fcsp_set_title_on_save')`

Comment: Tried it, I get a parse error when I add `add_action( 'save_post', 'fcsp_set_title_on_save' );` after the `wp_update_post` statement. (Unexpected `}`) When I remove the `add_action` again it is the same as before, no product title set.

Comment: I've updated code above, if it is woocommerce you are using then this might be some help for you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, but as I am a newbie, what am I suppose to place instead of the `echo $post_id;die;`? Using it without change it shows me a number. PostID number? Would you be so kind to help me out?

Comment: I've updated my code above, please use it, it will save your new product and take the title from product image you will add, but you'll need to at least add one other product info, like description along with image so woocommerce verify the nonce data while posting it, simply image won't do anything. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks that works great. Is there any way we can avoid giving in another piece of info? Price, virtual, downloadable and file download are set by another function could we use that? In the end I want to provide an interface with only one button: "select and upload image" and then the system has to do the rest. Next, I modified the code to create a slug from the title with `sanitize_title()` but Yoast is creating a 301 redirect on Publising the product. Any way to avoid that as well?

Comment: BTW, turning back to my original question, can it be done with JavaScript? I'm totally un familiar with JS but you never know....